# Fetching a unique information from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have user login table as "login" which contains all the information detail related to the user like  login date(datetime), name, etc .

And tables "users", "user_category" contains the user id for particular user category like workers,owner.

User can login more than once in a day.I want to fetch most recent one login information about user like login date and time so I applied "distinct" it works fine because I converted log_time from datetime to date using CAST(log_time AS DATE) .But I want time also .

Please suggest some method instead of distinct I used "group by " it's giving multiple record.
This is a query which I tried

```
(select  distinct users.users_desc as name,login.user_id,CAST(log_time AS DATE) as log_time
from login,users,user_category 
where (((log_time BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-10-01') OR  (DATE(`log_time`)='2015-10-01'))) 
and login.user_id=users.users_id and 
user_category.category_desc='WORKERS' and
 user_category.category_id=users.cat_id  )
```

sample :

```
This how my login table look like
name     user_id    login_time
"A1-C"  "userId_1"  "2015-06-04 13:01:22"
"A1-C"  "userId_1"  "2015-06-04 14:00:00"
"A1-C"  "userId_1"  "2015-06-12 00:00:00"
"A2-C"  "userId_2"  "2015-06-04 13:01:22"
"A2-C"  "userId_2"  "2015-06-04 14:01:00"
"A2-C"  "userId_2"  "2015-06-12 10:00:00"


I want output as :
name     user_id    date         time
"A1-C"  "userId_1"  "2015-06-04" " 14:00:00"
"A1-C"  "userId_1"  "2015-06-12" "00:00:00"
"A2-C"  "userId_2"  "2015-06-04" "14:01:00"
"A2-C"  "userId_2"  "2015-06-12" "10:00:00"
```

Comment: What kind of "time" do you want to get? For example, you have 2 records per login  in a day. Do you want to get both?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output

Comment: I want recent time of login .login_time contain date in this format " 2015-06-04 13:46:19"

Comment: And in your table definition login_time is a DateTime?

Comment: what is the format in Database for column  login.login_time ?

Comment: yes login_time is a DateTime in database

Comment: please use proper inner join, instead of comma between tables

Comment: @ullas I update by sample out which i expected please check

Comment: Could you please provide the sample data in the form of valid `CREATE TABLE ...` statements (as shown by `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`)  and valid `INSERT INTO ...` statements for all of the three tables involved + the expected result for that sample data. (and please double check the expected result, in your current expected result all records have the same user_id yet different names - is that correct?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with a few transformations on your query (so it's in a form *I'm* more comfortable with ;-) ).
First by making the format a lot more verbose

```
(
    select distinct
        users.users_desc as name,
        login.user_id,
        CAST(log_time AS DATE) as log_time
    from
        login,
        users,
        user_category 
    where 
        (
            (
                (
                    log_time BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-10-01')
                    OR (DATE(`log_time`)='2015-10-01'
                )
            )
        ) 
        and login.user_id=users.users_id
        and user_category.category_desc='WORKERS'
        and user_category.category_id=users.cat_id
)
```

The `...between ... OR date(...)` part can be simplified via

```
log_time BETWEEN '2015-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-01 23:59:59'
```

and then all of those parentheses can be removed. Also strike the `distinct` and your query looks like

```
select
    users.users_desc as name,
    login.user_id,
    CAST(log_time AS DATE) as log_time
from
    login,
    users,
    user_category 
where 
    log_time BETWEEN '2015-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-01 23:59:59'
    and login.user_id=users.users_id
    and user_category.category_desc='WORKERS'
    and user_category.category_id=users.cat_id
```

Now we convert the implicit to explicit JOINs

```
SELECT
    u.users_desc as name,
    l.user_id,
    CAST(l.log_time AS DATE) as log_time
FROM
    login as l
JOIN
    users as u
ON
    l.user_id=u.users_id
JOIN
    user_category as c
ON
    u.cat_id=c.category_id
where
    log_time BETWEEN '2015-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-01 23:59:59'
    AND user_category.category_desc='WORKERS'
```

(I haven't tested the query, so please check that it's still working - execpt that it now returns all the logins because of the missing `distinct`)

And now we apply [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual - 3.6.4 The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html). I choose the third version using a LEFT JOIN and IS_NULL (the optimizer is quite good with such queries).
You want the group-wise maximum of the login table. The "base query" (without the other two tables) would be

```
SELECT
    l1.user,
    l1.log_time
FROM
    login as l1
LEFT JOIN
    login as l2
ON
    l1.user_id=l2.user_id
    AND l1.log_time < l2.log_time
WHERE
    l2.log_time IS NULL
```

But apparently you want to the group-wise maximum per day within the given range. So we add another JOIN condition for that "grouping" (which is probably the biggest strain on the performance of the query)

```
SELECT
    l1.user,
    l1.log_time
FROM
    login as l1
LEFT JOIN
    login as l2
ON
    l1.user_id=l2.user_id
    AND Date(l1.log_time) = Date(l2.log_time)
    AND l1.log_time < l2.log_time
WHERE
    l2.log_time IS NULL
```

Now let's incorporate this into the "real" query.

```
SELECT
    u.users_desc as name,
    l1.user_id,
    l1.log_time as log_time
FROM
    login as l1
LEFT JOIN
    login as l2
ON
    l1.user_id=l2.user_id
    AND Date(l1.log_time) = Date(l2.log_time)
    AND l1.log_time < l2.log_time
JOIN
    users as u
ON
    l1.user_id=u.users_id
JOIN
    user_category as c
ON
    u.cat_id=c.category_id
WHERE
    l1.log_time BETWEEN '2015-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-01 23:59:59'
    AND l2.log_time IS NULL
    AND c.category_desc='WORKERS'
```

[Two notes: a) I removed the CAST(as date) and b) again completely untested and I usually make mistakes when building those queries blind ... please provide sample data as valid `INSERT INTO ...` statements for testing]

Comment: your query is fine if I use   WHERE condition as "l1.log_time BETWEEN '2015-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-01 23:59:59'"  But I need  where condition as l1.log_time BETWEEN '2015-06-01 ' AND '2015-10-01 '" ,It's giving multiple data

Comment: "But I need where condition as l1.log_time BETWEEN '2015-06-01 ' AND '2015-10-01 '" - Please elaborate. Given the additional `OR  (DATE(\`log_time\`)='2015-10-01')` I don't see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from users a
left join user_category b on b.category_id = a.cat_id
left join (
    --  this subquery will return latest row on each user_id in range log_time
    select * from (
        select * from login
        where log_time >= '2015-06-01' AND log_time <='2015-10-01'
        order by log_time desc
    ) c GROUP BY users_id
) c on c.user_id = a.user_id
where b.category_desc='WORKERS'
```